Inverse limit of maps
Let $\{u_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in I}$ be an inverse system of homomorphisms $u_\alpha: E_\alpha \to E_\alpha'$ where the domain and codomain are both abelian groups. What does it exactly mean for $\{u_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in I}$ to be an inverse system and what is the definition of the projective limit of these maps? I know the definition of the projective limit of an inverse system of, say, abelian groups, but how does one define the projective limit of homomorphisms? I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Without further context, it's just another way to say "inverse system of abelian groups," but emphasizing the morphisms of the system over the objects.

Such limits are limits in the arrow category of the category of abelian groups. This is the functor category $[\mathbf{2}, \mathbf{Ab}]$, so limits are computed pointwise.

So in great generality, if you have two diagrams $D,D':J\to C$ and a natural transformation $\mu:D\implies D'$, (if the limits exist) you will get a limiting "homomorphism" $\varprojlim D\to\varprojlim D'$. Here, $C$ and $J$ can be any categories. The data of a natural transformation $D\to D'$ is exactly the data of an "inverse system of homomorphisms" (look up "limit is a functor"). We just require all the following to commute: $$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}E_\alpha@>f_{\alpha,\beta}>>E_\beta\\@VV\mu_\alpha V@VV\mu_\beta V\\E'_\alpha@>>f'_{\alpha,\beta}>E'_\beta\end{CD}$$If I understand your context right, and you mean for $E$ and $E'$ to be inverse systems.

This clarifies it. Thanks.
